# the difference among "開く（あく）、開く（ひらく）、開ける（あける）"

Tags: verbs

i know that "開ける" involves subject and object, like :

> "窓を開けました"( windows opened, & implied someone did it ),

and "開く（あく）" only involves the subject, like :

> "窓が開きました" ( windows opened, & implied no one, maybe by wind blow ),

but i can't make it very clear if "開く（ひらく）" is similar or equal to "開ける（あける）" which i found only very few examples says so.

Comment: ひらく is both intransitive/transitive. 「窓がひらく。」 = "The window opens." 「窓をひらく。」= "(Someone) opens the window." And your second example has a typo. It should be 窓**が**開きました, because the subject must be marked with が.

Comment: @naruto thx for the correction~